# Excel VBA making up its own footer

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, format

Each time that I rn tis code on some Workbook I get double path in the footer of the page. This is realy anoying especially since I do specify in here that center footer should be empty. Can anyone tell me why is this code producing footer where contents or `.leftfooter` are replicated in `.centerfooter`?

```
Sub Print_Setup()
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
Dim Page As Worksheet

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
For Each Page In CurrentWB.Worksheets
    With Page.PageSetup
        .CenterHorizontally = False
    'Make sure there is room to make notes on the sides of the page
    'Page Margins
        .TopMargin = 0
        .LeftMargin = 14.4
        .RightMargin = 0
        .BottomMargin = 18
    'Footer
        .FooterMargin = 0
        .RightFooter = "&8Printed &D: &P of &N"
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .LeftFooter = "&8&Z&F[&A]"
    End With
Next Page
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this macro on my system (Windows 7, Excel 2003) multiple times, and did not find the same behavior.

One thing that I've found is that if you have a long path, it can occupy a lot of real estate at the bottom or top of the page.

What version of Excel are you running, BTW?

Comment: Thanks for the pormt response, I am using Excel 2010 on Win7.

Comment: What if you set the footers to nulls, and do a print preview?  Do you get the same result?   Another option would be to set them to nulls first, and then set them to the values you want.

Are you doing any other page setting stuff?

Comment: Yeah that did it, I set tehm to null. Realy not sure why this worked, but it did